# Rolling correlation between two numpy arrays

Tags: numpy

How can I do a rolling correlation over the last N rows between two 1D numpy arrays? Looping over each row and then taking the correlation between the two relevant slices is extremely slow. Is there a quicker way?

Comment: So, the first input is a 2D array and we are taking last N rows off it? What about the second input?

Comment: I have 2D array. I want to take two columns (1D arrays) of this and compute a rolling correlation between them over the last N rows.

Comment: Add sample case? Also, consider adding in the loopy version.